# Setup ACL on Ubuntu 12.04 with Chef

Tags: ubuntu, acl, chef-infra

I've been trying to figure out how to write a recipe that would install the ACL package and then remount the filesystem root with it enabled:

1. `apt-get install acl`
2. Add "acl" to the options in fstab
3. `mount -o remount /`

My attempt at a recipe is:

```
case node[:platform]
when "debian","ubuntu"
    package "acl" do
        action :install
    end

    mount "/" do
        options "acl"
        action [:remount, :enable]
    end
end
```

Unfortunately (and not surprising) chef doesn't know how to read the existing fstab entry for / and add acl to it without changing anything else so it's blowing away the existing options on the mount point.  Any thoughts on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to do it with Augeas:

```
# Install ACL and remount the root volume with ACL enabled
case node[:platform]
when "debian","ubuntu"
    %w{acl augeas-tools}.each do |pkg|
        package pkg
    end

    execute "update_fstab" do
        command <<-EOF
            echo 'ins opt after /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/"]/opt[last()]
            set /files/etc/fstab/*[file="/"]/opt[last()] acl
            save' | augtool
            mount -o remount /
        EOF
        not_if "augtool match '/files/etc/fstab/*[file=\"/\"]/opt' | grep acl"
    end
end
```

I don't really like the solution, but it seems to work.  There's got to be a better way though, right?

Comment: I've published a cookbook with your solution https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/acl